# Error in code this expression has type a list but an expression was expected of type a the type variable a occurs in a list

Tags: ocaml

This error occurs on two of my tasks and I do not know how to solve it pls
help

```
let rec ins (l1, l2) i = match l1 with
| [] -> []
| _  when i>List.length(l1) ->[] 
| _  when i=0 -> l2@l1
| _  when i<=List.length l1 && i>0 -> [List.hd l1] @ [ins((List.tl l1), l2) (i-1)];;

ins ([1;2;3;4;5] , [6;7;8;9;10]) 3;;
```

this code is supposed to insert 2nd list in 1st on nth element

The error message is highlighting this piece of code

```
[ins((List.tl l1), l2) (i-1)];;
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and saying

```
Error: This expression has type 'a list
       but an expression was expected of type 'a
       The type variable 'a occurs inside 'a list
```

Answer (score 1):

These "occurs" errors are very often, but still, are quite confusing. On a high level, it means that you're using an element of a list and a list in the same context. I.e., that the type system inferred that your list is consisting of itself, a sort of [Russel's Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox).

On a practical level, it means, that somewhere you used an expression that denotes a list, in a place where you should use an expression that denotes an element of a list (or vice verse).

In your case, the `ins((List.tl l1), l2) (i-1)` expression is already having the type `'a list` and you're putting it into an extra list `[ins((List.tl l1), l2) (i-1)]`, making it `'a = 'a list`, which triggers the occurence error.

Hope, this would be enough for you to fix your code. Good luck! :)

Comment: still don t get it i just want to input tail of the first list as a list recursively that usaualy works did i make a mistake while calling the function recursively

Comment: hint: just remove the brackets `[`, `]` around the highlighted expression